# Apache Druid occurs error code 405 with SQL insert

Tags: sql, database, druid

For the given data sample, I can ingest it using batch commit with an ingest spec, but I cannot insert it using SQL 'INSERT' statements, resulting in error code 405.

```
// sample data
{"time": "2023-05-02T00:47:00.496Z","cooperative": "ABCBT","factory": "BTS","area": "1","dev": "BP","phaseA": 1.111}

// insert SQL generated by Druid
REPLACE INTO inline_data OVERWRITE ALL
WITH ext AS (SELECT *
FROM TABLE(
  EXTERN(
    '{"type":"inline","data":"{\"time\": \"2023-05-02T00:47:00.496Z\",\"cooperative\": \"ABCBT\",\"factory\": \"BTS\",\"area\": \"1\",\"dev\": \"BP\",\"phaseA\": 1.111}"}',
    '{"type":"json"}',
    '[{"name":"time","type":"string"},{"name":"cooperative","type":"string"},{"name":"factory","type":"string"},{"name":"area","type":"string"},{"name":"dev","type":"string"},{"name":"phaseA","type":"double"}]'
  )
))
SELECT
  TIME_PARSE("time") AS __time,
  cooperative,
  factory,
  area,
  dev,
  phaseA
FROM ext
PARTITIONED BY DAY
```

I cannot even insert a sample [from the reference](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/multi-stage-query/examples#insert-with-no-rollup) either, encountering the same error 405.

What could be wrong, and how can I resolve this issue correctly?

Comment: Where are the INSERT statements that fail?

Comment: @TimRoberts On web-UI, choose `upload data`-`paste data(copy&paste the sample)`-`paser(next)`-`configrure schema(choose SQL tab, then start loading data)`, failed

Comment: What leads you to believe that Druid supports REPLACE or INSERT?  From what I read, it only supports SELECT.

Comment: @TimRoberts I thought that way too, until I saw this yesterday, making me quite surprised: https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/multi-stage-query/

Comment: I see.  That's a new extension.  Are you using version 24.0, and is that extension installed?

Comment: @TimRoberts I am using verison 24.0 exactly, however it doesn't work...

Comment: I would like to gently suggest that you would save yourself much pain by moving back to the well-known JSON ingestion.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your kindness, I was just trying to figure this out haha.